# MySQL GTID consistency violation

Tags: mysql, sql, gtid

I am trying to create a table from a select statement, and it give me a GTID consistency violation. `[HY000][1786] Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TABLE ... SELECT.`

```
create TABLE tags_mentions as
    select t.*, st.ts, m.user_id_from, m.user_id_to from Tags as t join Mentions as m
        on t.status_id = m.status_id AND m.user_id_from != m.user_id_to
        left join Statuses as st on t.status_id = st.status_id;
```

What is GTID consistency, and how can I fix the SQL statement to avoid the violation?

Comment: Are you using a replicated server?

Comment: @Hogan Tags tables has 'tag' and 'status_id'. I can run the select statement alone and get the results. However creating table give the error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean by "replicated server"? I am using Datagrip (JetBrains application for database management) connecting to MySQL server on Google Cloud Platform. Hope this might be the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` is not safe for statement-based replication. When using row-based replication, this statement is actually logged as two separate events — one for the creation of the table, and another for the insertion of rows from the source table into the new table just created.

When this statement is executed within a transaction, it is possible in some cases for these two events to receive the same transaction identifier, which means that the transaction containing the inserts is skipped by the slave. Therefore, `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` is not supported when using GTID-based replication.

Answer (score 42):

If you want to fix the error another way, you can concisely create the table and insert separately with:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table; 
INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score 9):

From here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-gtids.html

> Since only transactionally safe statements can be logged when `--enforce-gtid-consistency` is enabled, it follows that the operations listed here cannot be used with this option:
>
> - `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` statements
> - `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statements inside transactions
> - Transactions or statements that update both transactional and non-transactional tables

You seem to have enforce GTID set. So this statement is not allowed.

Comment: This is great information. Do you have an idea why CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statement can be unsafe? Is it because the results of SELECT statement can be different at any time? Do I need root permission to disable this option?

Comment: Probably because it uses a temporary non transactional table before it builds the final table, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: The workaround I use for this is to create a table with the same schema by copying the create statement for the original table and then do a ```INSERT ... SELECT``` statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Stian of course creating the table and inserting is a "work around".  The question was how to NOT do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care to replicate it on the slave, you can turn off the binlog:

```
set sql_log_bin=0;
create table ... select ...
```